# “hard-linking” parts of a big file in which only a small part has changed

Tags: linux, filesystems, backup, rsync, hard-link

I use rsync to make backups:

```
rsync -a --link-dest=PATHTO/$PREVIOUSBACKUP $SOURCE $CURRENTBACKUP
```

This way I save space due to using hard links.

The problem appears when I need to backup a huge file which is always changing (virtual machine image).

Is it possible to hardlink not whole the image, but only it's changed parts? Is there any kind of tool that can take care of this?

Comment: The key that may help finding an answer is "incremental backup" or "delta backup".

Comment: Yes, in your case I'd go with a different backup system that can do incrementals / differentials. E.g., bacula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things that could be done here. Note that none of them actually use hard links since they can only point to a full file. Using the `btrfs` filesystem opens up some very useful possibilities here. Note that `btrfs` is currently (most recent version is v3.13) still experimental. However, its [COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write#Copy-on-write_in_computer_storage) (copy-on-write) ability is perfect for this kind of thing (provided of course that it is acceptable to have the backup on the same filesystem). Consider a `btrfs` filesystem mounted on `/mnt`, you can make an atomic snapshot of the whole filesystem with:

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot /mnt /mnt/snapshot
```

To allow for partial snapshots, you have to put your files to be backed up inside a `subvolume` rather than a directory. Eg:

```
btrfs subvolume create /mnt/subvol
mv stuff /mnt/subvol
btrfs subvolume snapshot /mnt/subvol /mnt/subvol_snapshot
```

Aside from using `btfrs`, you could also consider mounting the virtual machine image on one or both sides of the backup and using `rsync` between the two mount points.

[This blog](http://bethesignal.org/blog/2011/01/05/how-to-mount-virtualbox-vdi-image/) shows how to mount a Virtual Box `.vdi` image using `qemu-utils`. The commands as root (untested):

```
modprobe nbd
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 <vdi-file>
mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt
...
umount /mnt
qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
```

Finally, the simplest approach which may be of some use is the `--inplace` option for `rsync`. From the man page:

```
--inplace
          This option changes how rsync transfers a file when its data needs to
          be updated: instead of the default method of creating a new copy of the
          file and moving it into place when it is complete, rsync instead writes
          the updated data directly to the destination file.
...
          This option is useful for transferring large files with block-based
          changes or appended data, and also on systems that are disk bound, not
          network bound.
```

The problem here of course is that there isn't any benefit to using this in combination with `--link-dest` (in `rsync` versions <2.6.4 the two are incompatible altogether) as a copy of the file will still have to be created at the destination.

Comment: `btrfs` snapshotting is not a backup, if the underlying storage breaks, then your data is still (partially) lost. The `--inplace` option is unfortunately not going to help either, the OPs usage concerns using rsync as a snapshotting tool. Nevertheless, your suggestion of mounting a image is still helpful (+1).

Comment: @Lekensteyn, updated, I forgot about the `--link-dest`. The `btrfs` snapshot is still effectively a backup, but, yes, it doesn't protect against the same range of data loss cases as backing up to a different filesystem/location. Note, however, that `btrfs` can span multiple disks.

Comment: You can use `btrfs-send` to send your snapshots to another btrfs volume (or just save the stream as a file anywhere else) to make off-site incremental backups.